# сделать транзакцию при записи в базу данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

Есть метод который принимает List и этот метод записывает эти данные в базу данных, я хочу чтоб все это происходило транзакционно, и если где-нибудь произойдет ошибка, чтобы произошел Rollback.

```
 public async Task Insert(List<Details> prob)
 {
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(con))
            {
                //OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

                foreach (var item in prob)
                {
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INF.PROBLEM.INSERT_P", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.P;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("PH", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.PH;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("PL", OracleDbType.Number).Value = Int32.Parse(item.PL);

                        await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();

                        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                }
                //trans.Rollback();
            }
   }
```

Comment: А что вам мешает-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov я не знаю как это делаеться

Comment: `await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();` вынесите это из цикла, как я вам показывал в прошлом ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

команду заранее определяем и выполняем с новыми значениями из цикла (откат для всех значений из цикла):

```cs
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(con))
{
    await conn.OpenAsync();

    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INF.PROBLEM.INSERT_P", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;          

        OracleParameter param1  = new OracleParameter("P", OracleDbType.VarChar);
        OracleParameter param2  = new OracleParameter("PH", OracleDbType.VarChar);
        OracleParameter param3  = new OracleParameter("PL", OracleDbType.Number);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);
                  
          using (OracleTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)) 
          {
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;                      
                try 
                {   
                    foreach (var item in prob)
                    {               
                        param1.Value = item.P;
                        param2.Value = item.PH;
                        param3.Value = Int32.Parse(item.PL);
                        
                        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }   
                    // Finally, commit all the inserts
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (DataException e) {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }                         
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня в List 3 елемента когда foreach доходит до третего елемента я делаю DataException и в catch делаеться Rollback но с БД те 2 запись не удаляються

Comment: исправил ответ, учитывая передачу новых значений параметров в цикле

Comment: таже проблемаа.

Comment: если вам нужно делать общий откат всех значений из вашего цикла, то вынесите транзакцию за пределы цикла. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Если Автора вопроса, также интересует как использовать Dapper, то в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/DapperDemo), код учебного примера, для реализации CRUD-оперций в ASP.NET Core с помощью micro-ORM Dapper, с пояснениями на русском.